# Other cryptorurrency use in smart contracts

Tags: contract-invocation, bitcoin, altcoin

Is it possible to use other cryptocurrency than Ether (for example, Bitcoin, Litecoin etc.) within Ethereum smart contracts? I can imagine this will not really be compatible except for other currency being burned? (read I will provably burn Bitcoin and the smart contract will give me some Ether for it?)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to directly store or manipulate other cryptocurrencies from within an Ethereum smart contract. There are some services such as [BTC Relay](http://btcrelay.org/) which make this possible, but it is not a native capability of Ethereum.